# Is it possible to train dogs to detect Hypoglycemia?

Tags: dogs, training

Is there any evidence that dogs can detect hypoglycemia in humans? If yes, how is that possible?

How is it possible that we can use that ability to train a dog to alert a diabetic when sugar levels are critical?

Comment: is there a reason why you wanted to ask this or for research? Could we have some background info?

Comment: I'd start by deleting the "how" and asking whether there is any solid evidence at all that they can do so. Lots of anecdotes, but that may be reporting bias; we don't hear about the times when a dog alerted on nothing.

Comment: Your question is getting more clear, but right now I think the problem is that there is a string of questions. We prefer to have only one question per question block, that way we can have people answer the entire question, and make it easier for people to follow in the future. Is there any way you can either combine them into a single question, or at least into separate but related questions?

Comment: This question made me think of the research that's been going on with training dogs to detect cancer cells: http://www.dogsdetectcancer.org/dogs-detect-cancer-blog/dogs-smell-cancer

Comment: @DerrickK. I live with a diabetic, and I found there are courses you can take to supposedly train your dog to alert in case of hypoglycemia. I'm a skeptic so I'm looking for scientific/biologic background into this, since I can't find much information.

Comment: @Spiderman Thank your for the edit and advice. I'm trying to compile everything into one question because they are all related topics in my opinion. If you think I should divide into different questions, I have no problem doing that.

Comment: @Cthulhu Have you considered asking this on [Skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)? (Not that it's off-topic here, just that they might be better positioned to confirm/deny the claims.)

Comment: @Cthulhu Thanks for the information. That could help in answering your question.

Comment: No guarantees on the quality of these papers, but it could be a place to start: http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/abs/10.1089/acm.2008.0288 and http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/abs/10.1089/dia.2007.0215

Comment: There is a study from 2013 which showed that they could not detect it from skin swabs (so, by the scent). http://care.diabetesjournals.org/content/36/7/e98.extract  but they say behavioural effects have not been studied yet. So maybe some dogs basically react to the behavioural change of their owners.